# ./target/release/parachain-collator not found

Tags: parachain, parachain-collator, chainspec, substrate-parachain-template

Following [this tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/local-parachain/).

I'm trying to run this command in the `substrate-parachain-template` folder (found [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template)):

```
./target/release/parachain-collator build-spec --disable-default-bootnode > rococo-local-parachain-plain.json
```

However, I get this error:

```
./target/release/parachain-collator: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it? I've already run `cargo b -r`, so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the name should be [parachain-template-node](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/blob/main/node/Cargo.toml#L2).